# Illegal start of expression java slick

Tags: java, expression, slick

I have this problem, and it keeps on throwing the illegal start of expression, and I checked the brackets, and I think they're fine. Here's the code: Also, it says that theres an error at line 30, which I don't really understand....

```
    public class Menu extends BasicGameState {

Image playNow;
Image exitGame;

public String mouse = "No Input Yet!";

public Menu(int state) {
}

@Override
public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {
    playNow = new Image("res/playNow.png");
    exitGame = new Image("res/exitGame.png");
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    g.drawString(mouse, 590, 10);
    g.drawString("Welcome to my Game!", 100, 50);
    playNow.draw(100,100);
    exitGame.draw(100, 200);
}
//slick counts from the bottom-left of the display, not the top-left, like java does

@Override
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException {
    Input input = gc.getInput();
    int mousex = Mouse.getX();
    int mousey = Mouse.getY();
    mouse = "Mouse coordinate x: " + mousex + " y: " + mousey;
    // x-min:105  x-max:300  y-min:  y-max:300
    if(input.isMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        if(mousex>100 && mousex<300) && (mousey>400 && mousey< 435) { //error
        sbg.enterState(1);
    }
        if(mousex>100 && mousex<300) && (mousey>300 && mousey <335) { //error
        System.exit(0);
    }
    }
}

@Override
public int getID() {
    return 0;
}
```

}
I really need help quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, the condition for an `if` must be completely surrounded by parentheses.  Change

```
if(mousex>100 && mousex<300) && (mousey>400 && mousey< 435) {
```

to

```
if((mousex>100 && mousex<300) && (mousey>400 && mousey< 435)) {
```

... and the other `if` condition similarly.

The compiler thought that `(mousex>100 && mousex<300)` was the entire condition, and `&& (mousey>400 && mousey< 435)` didn't make sense as the body for the condition.